# Inyección de dependencia (DbContext)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, entity-framework

Hice una app de 4 capas (presentacion, negocio, datos, entidades) en windows forms c#.

En la capa de negocio, hice una interfaz y que la clase herede de la misma. Le pasé a la clase como constructor el DbContext así podía tener acceso al context en todos los metodos sin instanciarlo.

El problema es que yo no puedo aplicar la inyeccion de esa clase, en la capa de presentación, ya que me pide que el objeto que quiero inyectar le pase un contexto.

Esta es mi capa de negocio:

```
namespace Narachi.Business
{
    public interface INarachiService
    {
         List<Campeon> ListChampions();

         void AddChampion(Campeon campeon);

         void AddUser(Usuario user);

         List<Usuario> ListUsers();

         List<Rol> ListRoles();



    }

    public class NarachiService : INarachiService
    {
        private readonly NarachiContext context;

        public NarachiService(NarachiContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public List<Campeon> ListChampions()
        {
            return context.Campeon.ToList();
        }

        public void AddChampion(Campeon campeon)
        {
            context.Campeon.Add(campeon);
            context.SaveChanges();

        }

        public void AddUser(Usuario user)
        {
            context.Usuario.Add(user);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public List<Usuario> ListUsers()
        {
            return context.Usuario.ToList();
        }

        public List<Rol> ListRoles()
        {
            var Roles = context.Rol.ToList();

            return Roles;
        }

    }
}
```

Esta es mi capa de presentación:

```
namespace Narachi.Presentation
{
    public partial class frmNarachi : Form
    {
        public NarachiService MainService { get; set; }

        public frmNarachi(NarachiService mainService)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainService = mainService;
        }

        public frmNarachi()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmNarachi_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }
    }
}
```

No puedo utilizar MainService para llamar a los métodos del servicio ya que viene como nulo al no pasarle un DbContext.

Comment: El DbContext debe configurarse también en el DI para que lo inyecte en la clase NarachiService. El DI se encarga de satisfacer las inyecciones necesarias dentro de las clases que contiene.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no usas ninguna `libreria de DI (inyeccion de dependencias)` que resuelva por ti las dependencias en los constructores.

Por lo que deberas hacerlo tu cuando ingresas al form

```
NarachiContext dbContext = new NarachiContext();
NarachiService service = new NarachiService(dbContext);

frmNarachi form = new frmNarachi(service);
form.Show();
```

De esta forma creas la instancia del `dbcontext` y la asignas al constructor del `service` el cual usas en el constructor de `form`, pero lo haces todo manual porque no usas ninguna libreria de inyeccion de dependencias.

---

Sino la alternativa es usar una libreria de DI que sea compatible con `winform`, como ser usando `Ninject`

[Dependency Injection in WinForms using Ninject and Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127763/dependency-injection-in-winforms-using-ninject-and-entity-framework)

creo que la parte importante es como resuelve la intancia del form, no usa el `new` sino que lo haces por medio de

```
Application.Run(CompositionRoot.Resolve<Form1>());
```

Ese `CompositionRoot`

```
public class CompositionRoot
{
    private static IKernel _ninjectKernel;

    public static void Wire(INinjectModule module)
    {
        _ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel(module);
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return _ninjectKernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

es el que permite instancia el form para resolver las dependencias configuradas en la libreria de DI

Pero a idea es que resolviendo la instancia del `form` desde Ninject resolveras ademas todas las otras dependecias que definas en los constructores

```
public class ApplicationModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<INarachiService>().To<NarachiService>();
        Bind<NarachiContext>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

Por supuesto analiza un poco la documentacion de Ninject para aprender como configurarlo correctamente

[Ninject wiki](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki)